# android - Master/Detail view with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, master-detail

I'm trying to use Master/Detail view with different layouts for tablets and smartphones with `NavigationDrawer`.

#### Situation

I use NavigationDrawer template from AndroidStudio: every page from side menu opening as a Frament. It's replaced into one Frame Layout (called `window_container`) in MainActivity.

So, *every page from side menu is a Fragment in MainActivity, not an independent Activity*. And this make me lot of headache.

#### What wrong with master\detail view?

Google recomends do something like this: 
[image]
we have two activities containing fragments. *But i have only a one activity for all windows and every window just a fragment!*

Also I so something like this: 
[image]
There is only one Activity and detail view replced with master view. This is closer to me.

#### What did I do?

I use my Fragments from navigation drawer as a `base` Fragment for Master and Detail Fragments. It works like an Activity for they:[image]

It has an Interface so child framgnets  can interact with it, for example - call method to show detail view.

I get reference to my base fragment in my Master and Detail view:

```
public void onCreate()
{
   ...
   my_base_fragment = (IMyBaseFragment)getParentFragment.
}
```

And there is a problem. When I use `getFragmentManager` in base fragment, `getParentFragment` returns `null`. So I use `getChildFragmentManager` and It's OK.

So, my work with fragments at all look like this:

1. For Master\Detail view fragments changing I use base fragments
2. To switch windows from NavigationDrawer side menu I use MainActivity, of course
3. If I need to show some new fragment I use method in MainActivity which replace it into `window_container` in MainActivity layout. (Important - this is makes me a lot of trouble). This method called `AddFramgnet`.

Why I need this? For example I have master\detail view and want to show some new window.
[image]

#### Very big problem

I use nested fragments and `getChildFragmentManager`. So, it has **independed backstack**.

**Situation**

1. I add detail view on a smartphone (child backstack contains 1 operation)
2. I press Back Button. In my `onBackPressed` I do `popBackStack` and ... *pop all my Fragment with Master\Detail view!*

So, I do something like this:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        //Скрываем меню, если она открыта
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else
    {
        //Проход по стеку открытх фрагментов
        //super.onBackPressed();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        //if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
        if (current_fragment != null && current_fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        {
            current_fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            //Log.d("Navigation", "Back: fragment popped from backstack. Backstack size: "+String.valueOf(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()));
        }
        else
            finish();
            //super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can see `current_fragment` variable. I set it when replace "windows" in NavigationDrawer side menu event or when I call `AddFragment`. It works, but not all time.

**Situation**
I need some Gallery in my app with 3 windows on a smartphone:

1. Albums list (`AlbumsFragment`)
2. Photos in album (`GalleryFragment`)
3. Photo preview (`PreviewFragment`)

... and a `BaseFragment` of course.

This a master detailed view, but on tablet albums view (master) looks strange, but it is not metter. And also 3rd fragment - preview, opens at a full activity on  tablets and smartphones both.
[image]

**What did I do?**

1. I use base fragment and show master\detail fragment
2. I call `AddFragment` from MainActivity to show preview.

When I show preview situation in backstack is like this:

Main Backstack:

1. Fragment `BaseFragment` replaced with `PreviewFragment`

BaseFragment child backstack:

1. Fragment `AlbmumsFragment` replaced with `GalleryFragment`.

When I pressed back the `current_fragment` is `PreviewFragment`, so I do `popFromBackstack` from main backstack and replace it with BaseFragments. Called `OnCreate` of It, It checked layout, doesn't see detail view and show ... albums list - Master View!

When I use `add` instend `replace` method in my `AddFragment` situation is different but bad too:

1. `PreviewFragment` removed, we see the `BaseFragment` with detailed view. Ok? No
2. When we press Back again app is closed. Why?

`current_fragment` is still `PreviewFragment`, it's child backstack is empty, so called `popFromBackstack` of Main Backstack and pop all master\detail view.

#### Question

**So, what I need to do?** I think the best solution is "Don't use nested fragments and `getChildFragmentManager`", but I don't know, how implement master\detail with NavigationDrawer without base fragments.